# Can we solve for $c$ in the equation $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-jc\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0$?

Tags: trigonometric-sums

This question was posted on stackexchange, but with no response. So, I thought it appropriate to post it here too. Let $N\geq 1$ and $0\leq k\leq N-1$ be fixed numbers, and $c>0$ be unknown. Suppose we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-jc\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0,
\end{eqnarray}
where $j:=\sqrt{-1}$. Equivalently, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \cos\left(c\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} \sin\left(c\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{N}-\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)\right)=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Is it possible to simplify and solve the above equations to arrive at a closed form expression for $c$ in terms of $k$ and $N$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you explain a bit where this problem comes from and what your preliminary ideas on its solution are.

Comment: No answer after one day?  Time for panic.... math.se link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843980/can-we-solve-for-c-in-the-equation-sum-limits-i-0n-1-exp-left-jc-sin